# How to measure time of execution of each "sub-process" of a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, automation

I'm running a program multiple times via script, but i need to get the time of execution of EACH time i run it. I'm trying to use the "time" function the same way as when i use it via terminal, but it doesn't really work. Here's my code with the "time" function inside the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
time ./tree < in_1.in > out_1.out
time ./tree < in_2.in > out_2.out
time ./tree < in_3.in > out_3.out
time ./tree < in_4.in > out_4.out
time ./tree < in_5.in > out_5.out
time ./tree < in_6.in > out_6.out
time ./tree < in_7.in > out_7.out
time ./tree < in_8.in > out_8.out
time ./tree < in_9.in > out_9.out
time ./tree < in_10.in > out_10.out
```

Note 1: Without the "time" before each line, the script runs perfectly. If possible, I'd like to put every recorded time into a new file, I tried using "echo", but haven't had any luck with it.

Note 2: Is there a way to make my script run with every file inside a directory, without specifically putting every and each one inside my script?

Comment: Feel free to correct my grammar, i'm not a native and would like the feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `time` command in the bourne shell (`/bin/sh`). Run your program with `#!/bin/bash`.

You can write recorded times into new files like this:

```
time ./tree < in_1.in > out_1.out 2> time_1.time
```

or if you want the time in the outfile:

```
time ./tree < in_1.in &> out_1.out
```

A very basic way of running your functionality for each of your `.in` files works with a loop and **pathname expansion** (using the `*` wildcard):

```
for filename in *.in
do
    time ./tree < "$filename" > "$( sed -e 's/in/out/g' <<< $filename )"
done
```

The expression `"$( sed -e 's/in/out/g' <<< $filename )"` is expanded to the result of replacing `in` with `out` in `$filename`. The double quotes around it prevent glob characters (`*`, `?`) and newlines in filenames from breaking your code.

`sed` is a very common tool but the substitution can be written even shorter using Bash-only **pattern substitution** (note the double `/` after the first parameter which equals the `g` modifier in `sed` triggering substitution of *all* matches of the pattern):

```
time ./tree < "$filename" > "${filename//in/out}"
```

Another very common approach of executing commands for a set of files found in or under the working directory is using `find -exec`, which may be difficult in this case due to the redirections.

Comment: `$(sed 's/in/out/g' <<< "$filename")` can be replaced by `"${filename//in/out}"` without spawning a subshell. Quoting it also prevents it from breaking due to spaces or glob characters. You could also quote the command substitution to this end.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thank you, modified my answer and also corrected some other stuff which was wrong because it was late (there are no null characters in filenames).

Comment: Actually there is an external executable, something like /usr/bin/time

Comment: @MaximNorin Yes there is a `time` binary, but I'm not sure how common that is, at least I don't have it.

Comment: It's pretty common. What "which time" tells you?

Comment: @MaximNorin What do you expect `which` to tell me if I don't have it? time is not installed on my system and I do not need it.

Comment: I'm just curious what system is that?

Comment: It is a Debian Wheezy.